# Could not create cart for customer using magento-2 REST API

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I need to create cart and get the `quote id` for the customer using magento-2 REST API but I am getting the following error.

> Error:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue
    [parameters] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fieldName] => customerId
            [fieldValue] => 83
        )

)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
$adminUrl1='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token';
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    $data1 = array("username" => $uemail, "password" => $upass);
    $data_string1 = json_encode($data1);                       
    $ch1 = curl_init($adminUrl1); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string1);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string1))                                                                       
    );       
    $token1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    $result = json_decode($token1, 1);
    if (!isset($result['message']) && $result) {
        $quoteUrl ='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine';
        $chQuote = curl_init($quoteUrl);
         curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token1)));
         curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $quote = json_decode(curl_exec($chQuote));
         print_r($quote);exit;
    }
```

Here I need to create the cart and get the `quote id` so that I can add the item into cart. Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plase update your script with below.

```
$adminUrl1='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token';
$ch1 = curl_init();
$data1 = array("username" => $uemail, "password" => $upass);
$data_string1 = json_encode($data1);                       
$ch1 = curl_init($adminUrl1); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string1);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string1))                                                                       
);       
$token1 = curl_exec($ch1);
$result = json_decode($token1, 1);
if (!isset($result['message']) && $result) {
    $quoteUrl ='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine';
    $chQuote = curl_init($quoteUrl);
     curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
     curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token1)));
     curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $quote = json_decode(curl_exec($chQuote));
     print_r($quote);exit;
}
```

You have to defined it as post request because by default it calls GET request. so update it and let me know if you still face this issue.

Comment: its returning only `202` after following your answer.

Comment: it should send the json response.

Comment: it will return quote id only

Comment: ok its the quote id.

Comment: order place after create customer when  that situation i m not sent welcome email.If you have any idea share with me and also i raised question my frnd in stack please check it "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260180/magento2-how-to-stop-sending-customer-welcome-email-when-order-created-using-ma"